# Test the remote client jndi lookup using arquillian

Tags: jboss, jboss-arquillian

Setup: arquillian, jboss as 7.1.1.final as a managed Container

I am currently migrating an EJB application from EJB 2.x to 3.x and JBoss 3.x to JBoss AS 7.1.
During this process i would like to get most classes under test and stumbled over arquillian.
While arquillian seems to offer some nice features on inter-bean-functionality i cannot figure out whether or not the testing of remote client features using jndi lookups works or not.

I used the Arquillian Getting started guides on my beans which worked, but since these are using @Inject and in my application jndi lookups are used everywhere i (at least think that i) need to swerve from that path.

Here is the TestCase i created based on [Arquillian Getting Started](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/). I explicitly left in all attempts using jndi properties of which i thought they might help.

The Test

```
should_create_greeting()
```

works if the Greeter bean using a separate Producer.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GreeterTest {
    public static final String ARCHIVE_NAME = "test";

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GreeterTest.class.getName());

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, ARCHIVE_NAME + ".jar").addPackage(Greeter.class.getPackage())
            .addAsManifestResource("test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml").addAsManifestResource("OracleGUIDS-ds.xml")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    return jar;
    }

    /**
     * @Inject works using a producer with {@code @Produces}
     */
     // @Inject
     // Greeter greeter;
     @ArquillianResource
     Context context;

     GreeterRemote greeter;

     @Before
     public void before() throws Exception {
         Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
         env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory");
         env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");
         // env.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT",
         // "false");
         // env.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS",
         // "false");
         // env.put("jboss.naming.client.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED",
         // "false");
         for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : env.entrySet()) {
             context.addToEnvironment(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
         }
         greeter = (GreeterRemote) context.lookup(ARCHIVE_NAME + "/" + Greeter.class.getSimpleName() + "!"
            + GreeterRemote.class.getName());
     }

     @Test
     public void should_create_greeting() {
         Assert.assertEquals("Hello, Earthling!", greeter.createGreeting("Earthling"));
         greeter.greet(System.out, "Earthling");
     }
```

}

Is it possible to get this test running with jndi lookup? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the Remote features of a EJB you probably want to run on the client side and not in container.

You can configure the Deployment to be only client side by using @Deployment(testable=false). The @Test methods will then run as if you were a remote client.

Beyond that you can just lookup the bean via the injected Context if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Does this work when using a managed server on which i deploy for a specific test or do i need to have a server with deployments running?

  I would really like to have the beans deploy during tests to a managed server and then run some tests against those. But if i try that e.g. using two deployments, i cannot seem to access the beans remotely.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so in a workaround i just added on the method to be tested the remoteejb as a parameter.
On my ejb:

```
public List localBean.obtain(RemoteEJB remoteEjb){
 return remoteEjb.obtain();
}
```

Then on the arquillian test :

```
@Inject
private LocalBean localBean;

@Inject
private RemoteEJB remoteEjb;


  @Test
    public void test(){
       List<Vo>voList =  localBean.obtain(remoteEjb);
    }
```

The best part is the remote ejb its injected and on the caller method original

```
@EJB(lookup="java:global/ear/ejb/RemoteEjb")
private RemoteEJB remoteEjb;
```